# Pointer issue, beginner example

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

```
class Person {
    ...
};

class Book {
private:
    ...
    Person *person;
    ...
public:
    ...
    Person *getPerson() {return person;}

    void setPerson(Person *_person) {person = _person;}
    ...
};

class Library {
private:
    vector<Book> books;
    vector<Person> people;
public:

    vector<Book> getBooks() {return books;}
    vector<Person> getPeople() {return people;}
    void addBook(Book _book) {//adds a Book to books}
    void addPerson(Person _person) {//adds a Person to people}
    bool checkOut(Person *_person, Book *_book) {
        if (_book->getPerson() == NULL ) {
            _book->setPerson(_person);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

int main() {

    Library lib("My Library");

    Book b1("The C Programming Language", "Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie");
    Book b2("Unknown Title", "Unknown Author");
    Book b3("Burning Daylight", "Jack London");

    Person p1("John");
    Person p2("Peter");
    Person p3("Ann");

    lib.addPerson(p1);
    lib.addPerson(p2);
    lib.addPerson(p3);

    lib.addBook(b1);
    lib.addBook(b2);
    lib.addBook(b3);

    lib.checkOut(&lib.getPeople().at(1), &lib.getBooks().at(1));

    return 0;
}
```

The program runs. If I put setPerson in a constructor in Book class, then it works. Why doesn't it work when I call checkOut method from Library class? Why isn't the checkOut method setting Person in the Book class, although it returns true ? What don't I understand? Thank you!

Comment: What specifically doesnt work? What is the result you are getting right now and what do you expect?

Comment: The first "issue" is you're using bare-pointers in a modern C++ program.

Comment: The checkout method returns true, but the Person field for the Book objects won't set. What should I use instead of bare-pointers in this case? I just started learning :)

Comment: Values. Or smart pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is this:

```
vector<Book> getBooks() {return books;}
vector<Person> getPeople() {return people;}
```

Both of these are returning the person and book vectors of your library *by-value*. Consequently, you're establishing the relationship in two vectors that have nothing to do with the actual vectors in your Library. They remain untouched.

Therefore, later:

```
lib.checkOut(&lib.getPeople().at(1), &lib.getBooks().at(1));
```

Does nothing to the *real* vectors your Library.

Change them to this:

```
vector<Book>& getBooks() {return books;}
vector<Person>& getPeople() {return people;}
```

Regarding how this should be done without pointers, thats another topic, but this should address your immediate issue.

Comment: how didn't I see this. Thank you! Have been checking for a mistake all day :)

Comment: @user2879175 Because if you barely look at code generally subtle mistakes pop out at you. If you stare at it *too* long the subtle mistakes are lost in the fog of your idea of what it is *supposed* to be doing. Take a break once in awhile, come back, and then rethink step-by-step what is you think is happening, then follow the code to see if its true. It helps.